# How do I use Mac/OSX key bindings with Spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, osx, keymap

I want to use Mac CMD+C for copy and CMD+V for paste in Spacemacs but I think it redefined CMD to Meta. How do I change this mapping behavior?

I found mac-key-mode but that package seems old and I don't know how to add it to Spacemacs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spacemacs has a "layer" called "osx" that should do everything you want.

https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Bos/osx

Just put `osx` in the `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` section and you should be all set.

If instead you just want to have some particular os x keybindings, you might find the ones below helpful:

```
  (let ((is-mac (string-equal system-type "darwin")))
(when is-mac
  ;; make fonts look better with anti-aliasing
  (setq mac-allow-anti-aliasing t)
  ;; delete files by moving them to the trash
  (setq delete-by-moving-to-trash t)
  (setq trash-directory "~/.Trash")

  ;; Don't make new frames when opening a new file with Emacs
  (setq ns-pop-up-frames nil)

  ;; non-lion fullscreen
  (setq ns-use-native-fullscreen nil)

  ;; Set modifier keys
  (setq mac-option-modifier 'meta) ;; Bind meta to ALT
  (setq mac-command-modifier 'super) ;; Bind apple/command to super if you want
  (setq mac-function-modifier 'hyper) ;; Bind function key to hyper if you want 
  (setq mac-right-option-modifier 'none) ;; unbind right key for accented input

  ;; Make forward delete work 
  (global-set-key (kbd "<H-backspace>") 'delete-forward-char)

  ;; Keybindings
  (global-set-key (kbd "s-=") 'scale-up-font)
  (global-set-key (kbd "s--") 'scale-down-font)
  (global-set-key (kbd "s-0") 'reset-font-size)
  (global-set-key (kbd "s-q") 'save-buffers-kill-terminal)
  (global-set-key (kbd "s-v") 'yank)
  (global-set-key (kbd "s-c") 'evil-yank)
  (global-set-key (kbd "s-a") 'mark-whole-buffer)
  (global-set-key (kbd "s-x") 'kill-region)
  (global-set-key (kbd "s-w") 'delete-window)
  (global-set-key (kbd "s-W") 'delete-frame)
  (global-set-key (kbd "s-n") 'make-frame)
  (global-set-key (kbd "s-z") 'undo-tree-undo)
  (global-set-key (kbd "s-s")
                  (lambda ()
                    (interactive)
                    (call-interactively (key-binding "\C-x\C-s"))))
  (global-set-key (kbd "s-Z") 'undo-tree-redo)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-s-f") 'toggle-frame-fullscreen)
  ;; Emacs sometimes registers C-s-f as this weird keycode
  (global-set-key (kbd "<C-s-268632070>") 'toggle-frame-fullscreen)
```

))